# TypeScript Convert Any Typed Array to a Generic Key Value Array

Tags: typescript

I have various array data that looks like this:

```
Countries: [{code: "USA", countryDesc: "United States"},{code: "MEX", countryDesc: "Mexico"}]
```

and

```
States: [{code: "NY", countryDesc: "New York"},{code: "VA", stateDesc: "Virginia"}]
```

What I want to be able to do is convert the specific code/countryDesc or code/stateDesc to a "generic" key value pair to use. Hence, my conversion routine would provide me with this:

```
[{key:"USA", value:"United States"},{key:"MEX", value:"Mexico"}]
```

and

```
[{key:"NY", value:"New York"},{key:"VA", value:"Virginia"}]
```

My goal is to write a function that takes in the array and the names of the properties for the key and value and then converts them to an array with a key and a value instead of the other property names.

What I have is this:

```
export interface IAnyArray {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

const convertToKeyValue = (
  array: IAnyArray[],
  keyname: string,
  valuename: string
) => {
  if (array && array.length > 0) {
    return array.map((a) => {
      return { key: a[keyname], value: array[valuename] };
    });
  }
};
```

I'm getting the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'IAnyArray'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'IAnyArray'.ts(7053)

for both a[keyname] and a[valuename] in the function.

This is how I would do it, specific to the input, but I'd like a "generic" mechanism if possible:

```
  const convertCountriesToKeyValue = (
    countries: { code: string; countryDesc: string }[]
  ) => {
    return countries.map((country) => {
      return { key: country.code, value: country.countryDesc };
    });
  };
```

I've searched the web and I'm unable to find anything useful to assist with this issue.

I'd appreciate any assistance in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to pass in an array of object of any property names, but *return* IAnyArray. Maybe something like this?

```
const convertToKeyValue = <T extends any>(
    array: T[],
    keyname: keyof T,
    valuename: keyof T
) => {
    return array.map((a) => {
        return { key: a[keyname], value: a[valuename] };
    });
};

const countries = [{ code: "USA", countryDesc: "United States" }, { code: "MEX", countryDesc: "Mexico" }];

const keyValueCountries = convertToKeyValue(countries, "code", "countryDesc");
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDcCmAnKAVEBpJBPAagIYA2ArkjALwwA86MSAHlEmACYQyFi4B8AFACgAkIRQpCuAFwx0AbQC6AGhEBrPGEIBbJDPW4QAM1krhCEuU069eI7MEBKKrxgBvESiRRSKMF3GSAHRahAAO-PyETpQu7sLCnt6%20bjD6MoRy%20lZIyjDmZLpccvmW2jkwAL4A3CIVDjXVgoLw0HAgpGBQKACWSJzUcq5tbIUARACqAMoAgqNKbR1duAAifcAyE2DdLGwwk1CELBCjlfNDoCMbALIAogAacwudKCtr10zdoCcVCjXN4K19EQCgBhdrPXr9NqIVAYbB4YHkfigRY9PrzUYXJCPTHgparCDAUb1QRAA)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, this should be what you're looking for:

```
const convertToKeyValue = (
  array: IAnyArray[],
  keyName: string,
  valueName: string
) => {
  return array.map((a) => {
    return {[keyName]: a.key, [valueName]: a.value}
  })
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQEEkBPQqKTEuAbwCg44BrYEgLjgGcYpkBzBnABumADYBXYB268kAgL5062CEm5wVSIWhgAVCAGlWANTGS4AXjgAKQSxIA5TAFspXHvwA0gkROBPXaQ85b0ZMCioOIlJyShIAbQBdOgBKSwA%20WkEoYBhxKCQ4cLiAOmdMMGtrTDSLTPpGRhy8gtp4%20wDgRI5MEvtPOHjfSU7uopLh4EVGeRS6RToAekX3WT44AFpMmX5NzNiqAB4aeyC1gcmz-nlMrbgDkmOkYAB3I3ZVr2ExK7kb5VU2lg%20nepj81gARM83qwIQMIb44YMTqwOABydAQCBoi5mNwYrEbSZo%20QDFEfNEAI3COO%20fnR1KgRLxJMScyAA)

> Side-Note: I'd recommend keeping `keyName` and `valueName` as the first two params (as I've done in the playground), to make the function more composable if you decide to curry it in the future.